# Removing a div with specific id from a html string using domdocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I have the following string

```
$string = '<div id="promo_MLTEST"><h1>Test Promo Add</h1><p>This should add a new promo</p><ul><li>Test List1</li><li>Test List2</li></ul></div>test product 1'
```

I am trying to use DOMDocument to remove the div with ID promo_MLTEST and just leave

```
test product 1
```

I have tried the following

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
$elements = $doc->getElementById('promo_MLTEST');
while($span = $elements->item(0)) {       
    $span->parentNode->removeChild($span);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object in...
```

referencing the line which is

```
while($span = $elements->item(0)) {
```

Can anyone help please?

EDIT

I have also tried

```
$divMeta = $doc->getElementById('promo_MLTEST');
$divMeta->parentNode->removeChild($divMeta);
echo $sContent = $divMeta->saveHTML();
```

which give

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function removeChild() on a non-object in
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of php / libxml can use `getElementById()` with your code (for instance PHP 5.4.20 & libxml 2.8.0 it works as desired). However, on lower versions (I'm not sure were the cut of point is, *and* whether it's OS related in libxml), it's not. This workaround works fine for me: add a DTD to your html:

```
$doc->loadHTML('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>'.$string.'</body></html>');
```

[see also the problem observed at codepad](http://codepad.org/nBMqR1eA)

... but it may be very version related. Try a `$doc->validate()` if it still doesn't work with a DTD.

Comment: Excellent - that is really useful, I have a really old Linux box that I cannot update at all so after reading your answer then I think it is almost definitely that. Also, thanks for the codepad example - It took me two minutes to fix this after looking at your code :-)